# What is this view in vim?

Tags: vim

What is this view in vim called, and what is it for?

Somehow when I type colon to enter a command in vim I accidentally bring up a view that looks like this. But I can't get it to happen consistently, and I don't know what it is.

Edit:
It seems to happen if I type "q:", instead of ":q".

[image: unknown vim view screen-shot]

Comment: I believe it is called command line history window. Check this page: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_command-line_history

Comment: @MelBurslan. That answered my question. Thanks. Perhaps your comment should be an answer?

Comment: @MelBurslan That page has a really annoying ad redirect on iPhone...

Comment: @Martijn: sorry, I am not an Apple Tax payer. Page came from my laptop. I'm pretty sure wikia.com is trying to make some money.

Comment: @procrastinate_later Just a link as an answer doesn't justify to be an answer on its own. As long as you found your answer, that's all it matters. Not where it came from.

Comment: @MelBurslan no need for the tax payer part. Was just making an observation. Thank you for your help with this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the [command-line window](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#q%3A) (keyboard shortcut `q:`, quit with `ctrl+c`,`ctrl+c`)

It shows a history of your previous commands, which you can navigate to and edit with normal (command) mode. Once you've finished you can hit `enter` to run the edited or reselected command.

A similar history window is available for searches (keyboard shortcut `q/`, quit with `ctrl+c`,`ctrl+c`).

Reference: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_command-line_history

Comment: You can quit it as you would quit any other window: `:q`, Ctrl-C isn't needed.